# Chart.js problema al minimizar navegador

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Estoy utilizando este ejemplo de chart.js: https://embed.plnkr.co/plunk/z3Qy9C

Lo tengo modificado para que obtenga datos mediante innerHTML contra un DIV. La gráfica funciona, el problema es que si minimizas el navegador deja de actualizarse y cuando lo abres pega un salto en el que no a dibujado la gráfica. He estado realizando pruebas y incluso en el ejemplo de arriba sucede. He visto otras gráficas con chart.js que esto no le sucede como por ejemplo: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/kkJJZE?editors=1010. No se donde puede estar el problema, alguna idea? Muchas gracias.

Comment: Podrías poner el código realizado por tí, además de los ejemplos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya he resuelto el problema. El problema es que la gráfica se actualizaba con un while y este necesita tener la pagina en primer plano para funcionar. En este caso lo he sustituido por un setInterval. Y así ya no falla.

```
setInterval(function(){
    progress();
    updateCharts();
}, 300000);
```